# How to exclude particular mail in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, When the build broke, it will get the list of culprits from SCM and email will send to culprits using "Editable Email Notification" plugin. My problem is I want to exclude some users from that that list of emails. Because they are no way related to that broke.

I found "Excluded Recipients" in Jenkins-> configure systems. But this option is to exclude from Recipients List.

Comment: How are you getting a list of emails? According to commiters or something similar?

Comment: Sends email to the list of users who committed a change since the last non-broken build till now. This list at least always include people who made changes in this build, but if the previous build was a failure it also includes the culprit list from there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Jenkins -> "Configure system" and add the users or e-mails you want to exclude to "Excluded Recipients".  When the plugin generates a list of e-mails it will exclude the ones you've added here.